# Wordpress plugin development jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have developed a wordpress plugin that uses jquery.

This plugin have some javascript functions/operations in custom js file.

As jquery functions, i have used `$` sign for selector.

Everything is ok up to now. However, some users use wordpress plugins that uses jquery and that plugin overrided `$` sign as `jQuery` or `$j`.

If i deregister my jquery.js, my plugin doesnt work, if i deregister other jquery.js other plugin doesnt work. For example, i am using twitter-bootsrap-modal.js in my plugin and it uses `$` sign.

When i install another plugin on my wordpress that uses `$j` system doesn't work.

Have you any strategies for that kind of situations?

Comment: How are you calling jquery? You should use `wp_enqueue_script();`, if you're not doing it already. Also, try using the following wrapper, like it is described in the wordpress codex: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /* Insert jQuery here */ });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using `$j` you should declare it using `.noConflict()`.

You can also use it for your plugin, Wordpress require it most of the time because it use different libraries.

So at the to of your plugin write:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); //$j could be also j, or $r, everything you want, is a variable.
```

Then replace all your `$` with your new variable used in the no conflict.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using what you said but, i am using third party libraries like bootstrap modal and it uses "$" for their functions. I can change my js functions to "$j" but what about third party js libs?

Comment: in your file everything will be always `$j`. Leave Bootstrap as default.

Comment: I tried no conflict and replaced $ with $sj and it worked, thanks